# How to install easyphp when I know nothing about Microsoft packages C++?

Tags: package, easyphp

Thanks for your help guys. I want to install a Prestashop website on my computer.

Comment: _Thanks for your help guys..._ What kind of help are you expecting here? Your request in its current format is kind of off-topic for SO.

Comment: What are you trying to do and what you have done is important.

Comment: You should read this : http://www.easyphp.org/faq_devserver.php#collapse001